# SwiftUI text randomly goes upside down when editing

Tags: macos, cocoa, swiftui

Whenever I edit text using a SwiftUI TextField, or the old NSTextField, my text randomly becomes reversed and upside down (see image below). It also rarely happens to normal SwiftUI Text labels when resizing the window. By random, I mean as you type, the text toggles back and fourth between normal and upside down.

[image: upside down text]

```swift
@State var text = "Hello"

var body: some View {
  VStack {
    TextField("Name", text: $text)
  }
  .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
}
```

Does anybody have an idea of what might cause this? I can't seem to replicate it in another project, but even when I comment everything out besides for the text field it happens.

Comment: It looks like the origin of issue in some other code? Did you flip coordinates anywhere?

Comment: No, I'm not doing any kind of coordinate manipulation. It's weird because it's happening in multiple windows with completely different code/content views.

Comment: Ok, I fixed it! It turns out the bug was caused by a NSView calling `NSGraphicsContext.saveGraphicsState()` and `NSGraphicsContext.restoreGraphicsState()` in the draw function. I'm not sure why, but this caused the text to break all over the app. It also caused random crashes that never pointed to those two lines. Crazy!